# MSVC contidion_variable clarification

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, condition-variable

Could somebody clarify the meaning of the bold part on this remark? If possible with a code snippet.

I can't identify what's referred as **calling thread** and **functions** in this context.

Is there any difference with the behaviour of `condition_variable` on linux (gcc + pthreads) ?

> Remarks
>
> Code that waits for a condition variable must also use a mutex. **A calling thread must lock the mutex before it calls the functions that wait for the condition variable. The mutex is then locked when the called function returns**. The mutex is not locked while the thread waits for the condition to become true. So that there are no unpredictable results, each thread that waits for a condition variable must use the same mutex object.[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874761.aspx)

I've a bug that shows up only on Windows. `notify_one()` seems to be ignored but the code works OK if using `wait_for()` instead of `wait()` (still trying to produce an MCVE for that).

Comment: possible duplicate of my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470773/possible-race-condition-in-stdcondition-variable

Answer (score 0):

**calling thread** is the thread that makes the call to one of `std::condition_variable::wait` overloaded **functions**.